# Is it better to put filefields of all models in another model or not?

Tags: django-models, database-design, filefield

Which of the choices below is better regarding the database design and other factors.

Option 1)

```py
class Profile(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    family_name = CharField(...)
    passport_number = CharField(...)
    ielts = ForeignKey(Ielts)
    education = ForeignKey(Education)

class Ielts(Model):
    reading = CharField(...)
    writing = CharField(...)
    spekaing = CharField(...)
    listening = CharField(...)

Education(Model):
    level = CharField(...)

class Document(Model):
    profile = ForeignKey(Profile)
    ielts_pic = FileField(...)
    passport_pic = FileField(...)
    education_transcript_doc = FileField(...)
```

Option 2)

```py
class Profile(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    family_name = CharField(...)
    passport_number = CharField(...)
    passport_pic = FileField(...)
    ielts = ForeignKey(Ielts)
    education = ForeignKey(Education)

class Ielts(Model):
    reading = CharField(...)
    writing = CharField(...)
    spekaing = CharField(...)
    listening = CharField(...)
    ielts_pic = FileField(...)

Education(Model):
    level = CharField(...)
    education_transcript_doc = FileField(...)
```

What if the number of Models(tables) is very large?

Is it better to distribute files (technically, the file addresses) in different tables related to its model or collect them all in an additional Document model and use foreign-key for each field of Document model to its respective `Model`?

Comment: The files are not stored in the database. These are stored in the MEDIA directory. Storing files in a database is usually not a good idea.

Comment: The urls are stored in the database. My question is about urls.